# Difference between types of sale activities for tokens

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, ico, crowdsale, airdrop

I want to underatand whats the difference between a crowdsale,  airdrop,  ICO, ILO, ipo and presale. Are all these types of presale activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see:

- Crowdsale: some way of selling tokens to the crowds. Typically a separate contract (or multiple) which handle the crowdsale.
- Airdrop: Token is assigned to a bunch of addresses (wallets) based on some criteria. For example the token is assigned to all addresses which have an Ether balance above 1 Ether. Typically the owners of these wallets don't even know they have received such tokens.
- ICO: Initial Coin Offering. Some way of distributing the tokens/coins. Typically a crowdsale but can be something else as well
- ILO: never heard of this one, google gave this which I didn't quite understand: https://medium.com/probit-exchange/ilo-initial-listing-offering-9a8c48080a94
- IPO: Initial Public Offering. Typically this term is associated with a company selling their shares. In blockchain world I believe the equivalent is STO: Security Token Offering which basically means that you can buy securities which signify a share of the launching company. These are still quite rare as the legal hassle to get this done officially is quite difficult to go through.
- Presale: a phase typically in a crowdsale where the token/coin is sold only to certain wallets and typically with a better exchange rate. After presale comes the main sale.

So, no, they are not presale activities.

Comment: And what would be an IPO?

Comment: ah, missed that one. added.